# How do you make a dynamic loop in JS/HTML like you do in Jade?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I kind of went and wrote ALL of my display code in html, with really specific attributes and stuff dropped in, and unfortunately all of the tutorials I have that show display templating only show it for Jade.

I want to do it in HTML and Javascript.

How would I go about doing

```html
ul
  each val in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    li= val
```

in HTML/JS?

Is it any more complex than just having a for loop that pushes tags around as strings when it's lower than x variable I pull from my database, or am I missing something?

I'd like to keep my abstracting no higher than Javascript, HTML, CSS, Node.js and Mongodb while I'm learning.

Comment: so you want to generate the li elements dynamically using JS?

Comment: yeah pretty much. if I draw 10 items from a collection, I want 10 li. if i draw 5, i want 5, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this purely by JavaScript.

First simply write a

```
function call(n){

    //Accessing the ul element
    var main = document.getElementById("main");

    for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
        var child = document.createElement("li");

        //if you want to add data to your li
        child.innerHTML = i+1;

        //appending the child to the main ul
        main.appendChild(child);
    }

}
```

Here, 'n' is the number of `li` you want to generate.

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/khomkz8q/1/)

Comment: `child.innerHTML = i+1;` to match the original Jade example.

Comment: Okay, this works, thanks. I would just switch out the id of the data I'm adding with whatever the id I'm drawing from MongoDB is right?

Comment: @ARMATAV ya that should work but just make sure the id you are fetching does not start with a number because that might result in issues in some browser, if it does then append some string to it Eg: id="a"+123;

Comment: Ah, gotcha. So like "user" + collection.get(_id) or something. cool!

Comment: @ARMATAV yup that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create elements like so.

https://jsfiddle.net/scheda/5p5nhdxh/

```
var thing = document.getElementById('thing');
var things = [1,2,3,4,5];

things.forEach(function(v) {
    thing.innerHTML += "<li>" + v  +"</li>";
});
```